# How to convert MySQL query output in array in shell scripting?

Tags: mysql, arrays, shell

I am storing output of MySQL query in a varible using shell scripting. The output of SQL query is in multiple rows. When I checked the count of the variable (which I think is an array), it is giving 1. My code snippet is as follows:

```
sessionLogin=`mysql  -ugtsdbadmin -pgtsdbadmin -h$MYSQL_HOST -P$MYSQLPORT CMDB -e " select distinct SessionID  div 100000 as 'MemberID' from SessionLogin where ClientIPAddr  like '10.104%' and LoginTimestamp > 1426291200000000000 order by 1;"`

echo "${#sessionLogin[@]}"
```

How can I store the MySQL query output in an array in shell scripting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can loop over the output from mysql and append to an existing array. For example, in Bash 3.1+, a while loop with process substitution is one way to do it (please replace the mysql parameters with your actual command)

```
output=()
while read -r output_line; do
    output+=("$output_line")
done < <(mysql -u user -ppass -hhost DB -e "query")
echo "There are ${#output[@]} lines returned"
```

Also take a look at the always excellent [BashFaq](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005)